# How to Display Text Boxes on to the first row of Grid View in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

i want to know how to display text box on top of the grid view..

like the attached image,

when i am insert / update / delete record, it retains the position of top.

i have no idea about this, any body help me.

[image]

because there is one to 10 records its not a problem,

more than 10 records means i need to go down the page,

its more difficult to use, so that i ask.

Comment: Can you show the code you currently have for this gridview?  All you should have to do is move the EditItemTemplate to the top instead of the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

would like to see code you have created for the same , 
easy way to do this is edit each row , which will be easier for beginner

ASPX will be

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>GridView Crud (Select Insert Edit Update Delete) Operations using Single Stored Procedure in ASP.Net</title>
<style type="text/css">
.GridviewDiv {font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Helevetica, sans-serif; color: #303933;}
.headerstyle
{
color:#FFFFFF;border-right-color:#abb079;border-bottom-color:#abb079;background-color: #df5015;padding:0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="GridviewDiv">
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvDetails" ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="productid,productname" OnPageIndexChanging="gvDetails_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvDetails_RowCancelingEdit"
OnRowEditing="gvDetails_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvDetails_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="gvDetails_RowDeleting" OnRowCommand ="gvDetails_RowCommand" >
<HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="productid" HeaderText="Product Id" ReadOnly="true" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblProductname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productname")%>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtProductname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productname")%>'/>
</EditItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtpname" runat="server" />
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Price">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("price")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtProductprice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("price")%>'/>
</EditItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtprice" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" CommandName="AddNew" runat="server" Text="Add" />
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Label ID="lblresult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

your code will be

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
BindGridview();
}
}
protected void BindGridview()
{
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Suresh;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MySampleDB"))
{
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("crudoperations", con);
cmd.CommandType= CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status","SELECT");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
gvDetails.DataSource = ds;
gvDetails.DataBind();
}
else {
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
gvDetails.DataSource = ds;
gvDetails.DataBind();
int columncount = gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
}
}
}
protected void gvDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
{
TextBox txtname = (TextBox)gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtpname");
TextBox txtprice = (TextBox)gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtprice");
crudoperations("INSERT", txtname.Text, txtprice.Text, 0);
}
}
protected void gvDetails_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
gvDetails.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
BindGridview();
}
protected void gvDetails_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
gvDetails.EditIndex = -1;
BindGridview();
}
protected void gvDetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
gvDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
BindGridview();
}
protected void gvDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
int productid = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["productid"].ToString());
TextBox txtname = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtProductname");
TextBox txtprice = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtProductprice");
crudoperations("UPDATE",txtname.Text,txtprice.Text,productid);
}
protected void gvDetails_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
int productid = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["productid"].ToString());
string productname = gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["productname"].ToString();
crudoperations("DELETE",productname,"",productid);
}
protected void crudoperations(string status, string productname, string price, int productid)
{
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Suresh;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MySampleDB"))
{
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("crudoperations", con);
cmd.CommandType= CommandType.StoredProcedure;
if(status=="INSERT")
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status",status);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname",productname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price",price);
}
else if(status=="UPDATE")
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status",status);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname",productname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price",price);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productid",productid);
}
else if(status=="DELETE")
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status",status);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productid",productid);
}
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
lblresult.Text = productname+" details "+status.ToLower()+"d successfully";
gvDetails.EditIndex = -1;
BindGridview();
}
}
```

for more over you can refer following link
[GridEdit](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html)
[Link which is neear to your req](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2015/07/aspnet-gridview-crud-operations-insert-select-edit-update-delete-using-single-stored-procedure-example.html)

[betterway](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-x-none.html)

If you are not happy with this provide snippet of your code people will help it to improve

Comment: i want to know how to display text box on top of the grid view.. i want to type entry in top of the gridview row index, (ie) 0. because there is one to 10 records its not a problem, more than 10 records means i need to go down the page, its more difficult to use, so that i ask.

Comment: well thats correct show some snippet of code that i can help  ,
else you can use above code  ,and just add small text box and search button , on click of search load grid ,then your problem will be solved ,
any how if there are N records you will need to have search  ,  utilize same search and your problem of scrolling down will be solved